# Can you test the_content() in wordpress for img tags?

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to make an if statement that tests if a post has images in them. If they do I want them to do one thing and if not I want them to do something else.

Can someone guide me in the right direction?

Comment: Would checking for a string match be a load on resources?

Comment: strstr would not have any effect really.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(($c = get_the_content()) && strstr('<img',$c))
{
    //has an image / you can use $c saves calling the function again 
}else
{
     //No image. 
}
```

that's the quickest way to do it, may not be 100% accurate thou.

Comment: this actually causes the content to be displayed twice.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using:

```
<?php       
    ob_start();
    the_content();
    $content = ob_get_clean();

    if(!strpos($content, "<img")) {
        the_content();   
    } else {
        echo '<img src="' . catch_that_image() . '" alt=""/>';
    }       
?>
```

`catch_that_image()` is a custom function I found that displays only the image from a post.

Comment: can you just verify why you need to start an output buffer ?

Comment: otherwise the content would be displayed. I just wanted to capture it into a variable. Maybe there's a wordpress function that does this by default but this works.

Comment: you can use `get_the_content`

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the built in featured image functionality?

```
// in functions.php
add_image_size('my-custom-image-size', width, height);

// in the template
if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
    the_post_thumbnail('my-custom-image-size');
} else {
    the_content();
}

//or via a filter
function my_image_replacement($the_content) {
    global $post;
    if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
        $the_content = get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'my-custom-image-size');
        // other stuff as necessary
    }

    return $the_content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'my_image_replacement', 11);
```